# when calling $emit: [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Object(...) is not a function" Vue 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, error-handling, vue-component

Everything worked perfectly fine until all of a sudden it didn't anymore.

I have a button with a on-click event. When I click on it, it calls the method giveToParent() which emits a string:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="giveToParent()">search</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
...
  methods: {
    giveToParent() {
      var sql = "select * from xxxxx where min_Price=20";

      this.$emit("clicked", sql);


      console.log(this.$emit("clicked", sql));
    },
```

In the parent (app.vue) it looks like this:

```
<template>
  <Menu_Filter @clicked="test()"></Menu_Filter>
</template>

<script>
import Menu_Filter from "./components/Menu_Filter";
import { loadMap } from "./packs/my_js_file.js";

export default {
...
  },
  methods: {
    test(value) {
      logInConsole(value);
      loadMap(value);
    },
    
  },
};
```

The error message is the following:
[image: error]
As you can see, it says object is not a function, which is true, because the $emit function seems to be a vue component. I can log something else with no problem, so it has to be the $emit function.

The weird thing is that it all worked and suddenly it didn't anymore. I even had an older version of this on my laptop and when I tried to execute it there, it failed as well.

I seriously don't know why is doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="giveToParent">search</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

This should do the trick, v-on does not like calling it as a function without arguments.

Comment: no, unfortunately this didn't solve the problem. I still get the same error.

Comment: Try the same in the v-on in the parent

Comment: still the same error. The strangest thing about this is that it used to work even with the giveToParent() and test().

Comment: Made a working example with the code you presented above: https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-pond-pb1wg - The `console.log(this.$emit)` threw some warnings, but I take it that was only to debug right ?

Comment: strange that it works on codesandbox but not in my application. I cannot think of anything else that would throw this error. And yes, the `console.log` was just to debug.

Comment: Did you update to vue 3?

Comment: no, I still use Vue2

Answer (score 0):

can you test with `click.native`?
I'm not sure but I opine you can solve it with this trick

```
<div id="app">
    <Menu_Filter v-on:click.native="testFunction"></Menu_Filter>
</div>
```

Comment: unfortunately I still get the same error, but I have never heard of .native before. what is it used for?

Comment: If you want to listen to a native event on the root element of a component, you have to use the .native modifier for v-on

Comment: can you check this line
`<button @click.native="giveToParent">search</button>`

Comment: The `$emit` function does not get fired when I use `.native`, because the `test(value)` method does not get executed